# unable to Launch php files in chrome browser

Tags: php

I am getting a problem loading php files in my chrome browser.
if i try loading the file it returns the html content in the browser.
and if i try loading with another browser, it works well.
any help?

the html content

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
<title>TEST PAGE</title>

<style></style>
</head>

<body> 
<a href='logout.php'> logout</a><br>
<h2> index page</H2>
<p>hello username</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[how the file appears in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqEm1.png)

Comment: _"it returns the html content in the browser"_ What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: In what other browser does this work? As far as I know, neither Chrome nor other browsers include a PHP interpreter, and I'm not aware of third-party plugins.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side programming language, it has to be interpreted on the server, therefore you will have to start a local web server which interprets your `.php` files, from the web server address you will see the interpreted code in your browser, and you will notice that all PHP blocks `<?php ?>` won't be there anymore, since the files are interpreted.

Accessing from `file://` protocol therefore won't work, you have to access the web server address, for example: `http://localhost`.

*No browser* understands PHP, since all browsers only understand HTML, CSS, JS.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  i am using xampp. may be there could be an error in my installation